# Efficient way to inspect Cookie creation in real time

Tags: cookies, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

I want to inspect what happens to cookies when I browse a certain website, in order to figure out how this website track some data.

I guess I can use the Chrome developer tools, and use the Network tab, and look within each HTTP requests one-by-one (there are about 100 of them) and check the cookie tab and look for "response cookies", right?

Is there an easier way to do this? some tool to simply see all cookies that were being created / changed?

Comment: [Cookie Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-monitor/ccalldmbpkkpjcfgahbnpeffakpdldhj)?

Comment: doesn't seem useful, it requires me to define cookie domain, name and value. I don't necessarily know any of these data.